# svg тег polygon как использовать атрибут points

Tags: svg

```html
// получилось нарисовать прямоугольник
<svg width="540" height="290">
  <polygon points='30,30 0,60 60,60'/>
</svg>
```

Объясните как использовать атрибут points знаю что сперва идет x а затем y
в примере будет первое число 10 - x а второе 40 это y
Нарисовать фигуру прямоугольник не получается

```html
<svg width="540" height="290">
  <polygon points='10,40 10,20 45,20'/>
</svg>
```

Требую **Alexandr_TT** в студию ну пожалуйста

Comment: у нас есть {специализированный чат по svg}(https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat)  там можно, комфортно обсуждать вопросы, как вы делали здесь в комментариях. Кто-нибудь, да ответит. Я, в летний период, подолгу и часто отсутствую на сайте. Плюсик вам за вопрос. Удачи в освоении SVG

Comment: Благодарю, подправил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Система координат в svg начинается слева сверху

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В прямоугольнике 4 точки, атрибут `points` тега `<polygon>` принимает последовательность узловых точек многоугольника, то есть в Вашем случае 4 вершины желаемого прямоугольника

```css
polygon{
  stroke-width:4px;
  fill:wheat;
  stroke:red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="540" height="290">
  <polygon points='10,10 10,200 200,200 200,10'/>
</svg>
```

Вот пример размещения точек при рисовании шестиугольника

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
polygon{
  stroke-width:4px;
  fill:wheat;
  stroke:red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" >
  <polygon points='250,300 280,350 340,350 370,300 340,250 280,250'/>
  <polygon points='250,300 280,350 340,350 370,300 340,250 280,250'
           transform="translate(-200,-200)" />
</svg>
```

PS: фигуры можно двигать поворачивать и масштабировать атрибутом `transform`, я добавил второй шестиугольник с теми же координатами и подвинул его влево и вверх на 200 пикселей

```
transform="translate(-200,-200)"
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94406/discussion-on-answer-by-stranger-in-the-q-svg--polygon---).